# Stripe Payment Conflicting -> MainActivity.kt extends with FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, kotlin-native

This is my native Android class MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity(), AudioServiceActivity(){}

**Error**
The AudioServiceActivity was extended already when I  started  implementing Stripe I also have  to implement FlutterFragmentActivity  with  MainActivity
But it causes errors.
How do  I  implement both activities with MainActivity?

#Flutter
#flutter_stripe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hC3M.png)

I  tried  composition and made interface for both

I tried to implement only one Activity at a time  and make Object of second Activity  to utilize but causing issue   still

Comment: Could you share your MainActivity class? Also, what is the AudioServiceActivity?

Comment: @tomerpacific
here is my MainActivity.kt


class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity(), AudioServiceActivity(),DataClient.OnDataChangedListener,
  CapabilityClient.OnCapabilityChangedListener,
  MessageClient.OnMessageReceivedListener {
 }

The  AudioServiceActivity is from audio_service plugin

Answer (score 0):

I  resolved this issue by,
I made an Interface for one class AudioServiceActivity(),
and overridden its functions in the interface.
Then implement my interface on Mainactivity.kt
And implement the override function in Mainactivity.kt
like this,

```
class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity(),AudioServiceInterface{
override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: android.content.Context): FlutterEngine? {
    return AudioServicePlugin.getFlutterEngine(context)
  }
}
```

and this is my interface

interface AudioServiceInterface {
fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine?
}